# Equivalent to mongo shell db.collection.runCommand() in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native, mongojs

I'd like to use full text search available in MongoDB 2.4. 
Text search is available through runCommand function e.g. `db.collection.runCommand( "text", { search: "keywords"})`. So, I'm wondering whether there is an equivalent to runCommand() function in mongojs or node-mongodb-native modules.

I know the question has been touched before but was never answered sufficiently.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw, I've tried db.executeDbCommand({text:'comics', search:"you"},function(err, result) {});. result.documents['results'] variable is always an empty array, though.

Comment: The invocation looks correct to me. Are you sure you're not just getting an error ? For example, when I try the command without enabling text search I get something like `{ documents: [ { ok: 0, errmsg: 'text search not enabled' } ] ...}` but note that `err` from the callback was still `null`. Even if you have text search enabled you still might be getting another error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment jimoleary. AFAICS there are no errors, here is the response: { documents: 
   [ { queryDebugString: '||||||',
       language: 'english',
       results: [],
       stats: [Object],
       ok: 1 } ],
  index: 200,
  messageLength: 200,
  requestId: 2,
  responseTo: 3,
  responseFlag: 8,
  cursorId: { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: 0, high_: 0 },
  startingFrom: 0,
  numberReturned: 1 }

Comment: btw, `'comics'` in aforementioned example is supposed to be the collection. Also, when I run the command from mongo shell I do get results, and `queryDebugString` key equals `"<keywords>||||||"` rather than `"||||||"` which means that my keywords are not even passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

runCommand support has been added! https://github.com/gett/mongojs/issues/62

Comment: Were you able to get mongojs working for this? I've tried with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found that as an equivalent:

```
collection.find({ $text: { $search : "your search words" }})
  .toArray(function(err,results) {
    // ..callback stuff..
});
```