# MongoDB and MongoJS - can't get runCommand to work for text queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

My goal is to use MongoDB's (2.4.4) text command from Node. It works fine from the command line. Based on this previous SO issue: [Equivalent to mongo shell db.collection.runCommand() in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002711/equivalent-to-mongo-shell-db-collection-runcommand-in-node-js), I tried using MongoJS (0.7.17) but can't make it go.  Here is the code:

```
mongojs = require('mongojs');
var products = mongojs('localhost:27017/mydb').collection('products');
products.runCommand('text', {search: 'a'}, function (err, docs) {
   ...
});
```

docs returns undefined and err is null. I can execute a normal function such as products.find() fine... and I can execute the search on the MongoDB command line. Anyone know how to make this go?

BTW, here is what docs contains in the callback:

```
{
    "queryDebugString": "||||||",
    "language": "english",
    "results": [],
    "stats": {
        "nscanned": 0,
        "nscannedObjects": 0,
        "n": 0,
        "nfound": 0,
        "timeMicros": 55
    },
    "ok": 1
}
```

BTW, if there's another approach to make this work with just the normal native driver, I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the native driver I can run a command off of the db object as follows:

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect(database, function (err, db) {
    if (!err) {
        db.command({ distinct: "Messages", key: "session" }, function (err, result) {
            //more code here
        });
    }
});
```

I noticed you are running the command off of the collection object, that might be the problem.

Comment: Yes, although the mongojs docs say that should work. I just ended up with a variant of what you proposed... running off of the database instead.Thanks. It looks like: 

    db.command({ text: 'products', search: 'mysearchterm' }, function(e, o) {});

Comment: Can someone explain the difference between using find and using the db.command?  Why can't I use the text index with find.  Wouldn't that follow the convention a lot better?

Comment: I am getting db.command is not a function, I have mongodb 3.0.6 and getting the same result with runCommand as well

Comment: @NaguibIhab thats because you have not included db name in the url. For eg: if you are using database url to connect as `host:port` it will give error so correct way is to either use url as `host:port/dbName` or use variable `let DB = db.db(dbName); DB.command({})`

Answer (score -1):

Yo need to call the command inside the db object, not inside the connect object

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (!err) {
        var dbo = db.db();
        dbo.command({ insert: "mycollection", documents: [{"test":1}]}, function 
(err, result) {

            if (err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }else
            {
                console.log("1 document inserted",result);
            }
            }
        );

        }
});
```